# Exception while try to connect to SSL (HTTPS) with untrusted certificate using Google App Engine(java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, https

I try to get connection using `httpsConnectionUrl`, `httpClient` or `urlFetchService` to `HTTPS` server with untrusted certificate and get `sslHandshakeEcxeption`.

I tried to use trust manager but it unavailable in Google App Engine.

Thanks.

Comment: We'd love to help, but more context is necessary to do so. Can you share the code you're trying to use to connect?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [doNotValidateCertificate()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/FetchOptions#doNotValidateCertificate%28%29) `FetchOptions` to disable certificate checking when using `urlFetchService`.

Comment: It still doesn't work and gives me `SSLhandshakeException`.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Rita could you provide a snippet of the code that's failing?

Comment: @Rita also it might be useful if you could share the url you're trying to fetch from in case it's a server issue